# Multiple Submit Options with wizard form and Wicked gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, wicked-gem

I looked at [Wicked](https://github.com/schneems/wicked) documentation, but can't seem to figure out my problem.

I have a multipage wizard form, and on this page I have 4 buttons.

I need each button to update a specific attribute in my model, and also submit the form at the same time.

I tried to do this with 4 different submit buttons unsuccessfully. I think the best way to do it would be to have a custom url and pass in a param, but not sure how to do this with Wicked.

Example

```
[button_a] => wizard_path, {option: "a"}
[button_b] => wizard_path, {option: "b"}
[button_c] => wizard_path, {option: "c"}
[button_d] => wizard_path, {option: "d"}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easiest to use the rails [button_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) helper

```
= button_to('Update A', wizard_path(@wizard, option: 'a'), method: "put" )
= button_to('Update B', wizard_path(@wizard, option: 'b'), method: "put" )
= button_to('Update C', wizard_path(@wizard, option: 'c'), method: "put" )
= button_to('Update D', wizard_path(@wizard, option: 'd'), method: "put" )
```

The params you get from the controller, would be something like

```
params { id: 123, option: 'a' }
```

From there all you know is that button "A" was pressed on the wizard #123